# "Slide" transition does not work with latest MS IE and Flexslider 2.2.0

Tags: internet-explorer, fade, flexslider

Changed to 2.2.0 to solve som bugs that gave me problems with styling overlay captions. That worked fine - but now I have the issue in the title. All other browsers (including on iOS and Android) work great, per usal, it's IE that messes things up.

As soon as I put the old 2.1.7 files back (only use the two js-files) it works fine again (fades in IE as well). The overlay problems are even worse though so I do not want to go back.

Very very happy if some smart person out there has figured this out (or can give me more precise pointers on how to solve by using some other script time supplied with flexslider, not comfortable with that so I have not tried).